# Capturing user input data in a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

I created 2 UITextFields for the user to enter data (Int) into. I then want to create a var from the user input data to use in some equations. How do I go about recording the data that the user inputed into the blocks?

My code currently looks like this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
              
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIInputViewController.dismissKeyboard))

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func sMinInput(_ sender: UITextField) {
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func sMaxInput(_ sender: UITextField) {
        
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! The first thing you'll want to do is create a couple of `var`s in your `ViewController` class to store the user input. Add them just above `override func...`, then in your `@IBAction`s, you can say that you want to store the value in your vars. Then you'll be able to do whatever you'd like with them.

Comment: Tnx for the comment and advice. I also had to change the Type on IBAction to "sender: Any" in stead of "sender: UITextField". I got some response in the App the moment I changed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me. The key is to set your `IBAction` using whichever "Sent Event" you'd like. I chose "Editing Changed". You can add as many UITextFields (or anything, really) you'd like. Good luck!

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var text: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func textFieldAction(_ sender: Any) {
        text = textField.text
        printWithUnderscore()
    }
    
    private func printWithUnderscore() {
        guard let str = text else { return }
        print("_\(str)")
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture input data in a UITextField using following method.

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // This method is called when the user taps the return key on the keyboard
    textField.resignFirstResponder() // Hide the keyboard
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // Call at the end
    if let text = textField.text {
        // User input goes here.
        print("User input: \(text)")
    }
}
```

}